# Swift function calls

Tags: ios, swift, function, button

How to know how many times button got pressed or how to keep track of function calls in Swift even if we close the app, I have a button when you press it displays an alert I want my app to remember if the button got pressed more than once than I don’t want to display anything,do I need database for it?

Comment: You can use UserDefaults to save that data between app sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the count in **`UserDefaults`** when pressing the `button`.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var count = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "buttonPressedCount")
    count += 1
    print(count)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(count, forKey: "buttonPressedCount")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use User Defaults for getting to know whether the button was pressed previously

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Key") //setting value
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Key"). //getting value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `@propertyWrapper` struct to conveniently access `UserDefaults`.

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct DefaultsStorable<T> {

    private let defaultValue: T
    private let defaults: UserDefaults
    private let key: String

    init(key: String, defaults: UserDefaults = .standard, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaults = defaults
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            defaults.value(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```swift
@DefaultsStorable(key: "numberOfButtonClicks", defaultValue: 0) var buttonClicks: Int
```

You can then just increment the value any time the button is pressed